# If selected value is yes in Dropdown, Then show the other Field or hide

Tags: angular

I have three Input fields, For 2nd Input Field I have a dropdown with 2 values.If I selected value is Yes, Then It should show 3rd Input field, Otherwise 3rd Input field should Hide.
I am new to Angular, Can anyone help me in this??

```
<div >
  <ul id="menu">
      <li><input   type ="text" style="border:none" placeholder="Is this partner a PEP?">
        <div class="select"> 
            <select name="slct" id="slct"> 
                <option></option> 
                <option value="1">yes</option> 
                <option value="2">No</option> 
                 </select> 
        </div> 
         </li>
      <li><input type ="text" style="border:none" placeholder=" Does this partner blacklisted?">
        <div class="select"> 
            <select name="slct" id="slct"> 
                <option></option> 
                <option value="1">yes</option> 
                <option value="2">No</option> 
                 </select> 
        </div> 
      </li>
      <li><input type ="text" style="border:none" placeholder="Blacklist(s)"></li>
        </ul> 
      </div>
```

Comment: *ngIf is your friend :) https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<li>
    <div class="select"> 
        <select name="slct" id="slct" [(ngModel)]="selectedOption"> 
            <option></option> 
            <option value="1">yes</option> 
            <option value="2">No</option> 
        </select> 
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <input *ngIf="selectedOption=='1'" type ="text" style="border:none" placeholder="Blacklist(s)">
</li>
```

Using `ngModel` you will bind it with a variable `selectedOption`, based on the condition using `*ngIf` it will display the 3rd input.

Answer (score 0):

In your html file on second input include a change event and pass the event value to your ts file. In your third input element use *ngIf structural directive to add or remove this input field into the DOM.

```
<div>
<ul id="menu">
    <li><input type="text" style="border:none" placeholder="Is this partner a PEP?">
        <div class="select">
            <select name="slct" id="slct">
                <option></option>
                <option value="1">yes</option>
                <option value="2">No</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><input type="text" style="border:none" placeholder=" Does this partner blacklisted?">
        <div class="select">
            <select name="slct" id="slct" (change)="onChangeSecondInputField($event.target.value)">>
                <option></option>
                <option value="1">yes</option>
                <option value="2">No</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><input *ngIf="isThirdInputFieldVisible" type="text" placeholder="Blacklist(s)"></li>
</ul>
```

in your ts file declare a variable to keep track of the dropdown value change and on onchange change it's value accordingly.

```
isThirdInputFieldVisible: boolean = false;
 onChangeSecondInputField(value) {
   if (value == 1) {
   this.isThirdInputFieldVisible = true;
   } else if (value == 2) {
   this.isThirdInputFieldVisible = false;
 }
}
```